# Combination of types using boost::mpl

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, boost-mpl

I have a list of types, from which I want to construct the list of all combinations with two elements. For example:

```
namespace mpl = boost::mpl;
typedef mpl::vector<int, long> typelist;
// mpl magic...
// the wanted list is equivalent to:
typedef mpl::vector<pair<int, int>, pair<int, long>,
                    pair<long, int>, pair<long, long> > combinations;
```

Here, `pair<T1,T2>` could be `std::pair<T1,T2>`, or `mpl::vector<T1,T2>`.
How to do this?
I would also be interested in removing the duplicates when we consider that `pair<T1, T2> == pair<T2, T1>`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of combinations of a single type `int` with the list of types `mpl::vector<int, long>` can be computed by invoking `mpl::fold`:

```
typedef fold<
    mpl::vector<int, long>, vector<>, 
    push_back<mpl::_1, std::pair<int, mpl::_2> > 
>::type list_of_pairs;
```

Now, if we wrap that into a separate meta-function and invoke it for all types of the initial typelist we get:

```
typedef mpl::vector<int, long> typelist;

template <typename T, typename Result>
struct list_of_pairs
  : mpl::fold<typelist, Result, 
        mpl::push_back<mpl::_1, std::pair<T, mpl::_2> > > 
{};

typedef mpl::fold<
    typelist, mpl::vector<>, mpl::lambda<list_of_pairs<mpl::_2, mpl::_1> >
>::type result_type;

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT(
    mpl::equal<result_type, 
        mpl::vector4<
            std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int,long>,
            std::pair<long,int>, std::pair<long,long> 
        > >::value);
```

---

EDIT: answering second question:

Making the result containing only unique elements (in the sense you mentioned) is a bit more involved. First you need to define a meta function comparing two elements and returning mpl::true_/mpl::false_:

```
template <typename P1, typename P2>
struct pairs_are_equal
  : mpl::or_<
        mpl::and_<
            is_same<typename P1::first_type, typename P2::first_type>,
            is_same<typename P1::second_type, typename P2::second_type> >,
        mpl::and_<
            is_same<typename P1::first_type, typename P2::second_type>, 
            is_same<typename P1::second_type, typename P2::first_type> > >
{};
```

Then we need to define a meta-function which tries to find a given element in a given list:

```
template <typename List, typename T>
struct list_doesnt_have_element
  : is_same<
        typename mpl::find_if<List, pairs_are_equal<mpl::_1, T> >::type, 
        typename mpl::end<List>::type>
{};
```

Now, this can be utilized to build a new list, making sure no duplicates are inserted:

```
typedef mpl::fold<
    result_type, mpl::vector<>,
    mpl::if_<
        mpl::lambda<list_doesnt_have_element<mpl::_1, mpl::_2> >, 
        mpl::push_back<mpl::_1, mpl::_2>, mpl::_1>

>::type unique_result_type;
```

All this is from the top of my head, so it may need some tweaking here or there. But the idea should be correct.

---

EDIT: minor corrections as outlined by @rafak

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know how to use mpl::lambda. With the material about mpl you gave in your answer, I think I would be able now to answer my own question.

Comment: Note: I can't edit your post, so here is the little changes I needed:
in `list_doesnt_have_element`, replace `end<List>` by `typename end<List>::type`, idem for find_if. Also, I had to replace `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(is_same<` by `BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((mpl::equal<`, and another parenthesis at the end. I will remove this comment if someone can edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question. There are many interesting ways to solve this. Here is one.

All the unqualified names are in the `mpl` namespace, except for `_1` and `_2` which are in `mpl::placeholders` and `boost::is_same`, which is found in the type_traits library. The first template is a helper class to generate a list of all pairs consisting of a single element and each element of the given sequence. The second template aggregates all the results together to form the final sequence. Note that the results are not in a vector. You can do that easily with mpl::copy.

```
template <class Elem, class Seq>
struct single_combo {
    typedef typename transform<Seq
            ,lambda< std::pair<Elem, _1> >
        >::type type;
};

template <class Seq>
struct combo {
    typedef typename unique<Seq, is_same<_1,_2> >::type U;
    typedef typename fold<
        typename transform<U
            ,lambda< single_combo<_1, U> >
            >::type
        ,empty_sequence
        ,lambda< joint_view<_1,_2> >
    >::type type;
};

typedef typename combo<typelist>::type combinations;
```

---

Side note: If you're reading this and want a challenge, try answering this question yourself. It's a great plunge into MPL.

Comment: Excellent answer! thanks. I didn't know about the views. So I tried to replace the `transform` inside the `fold` by `transform_view`, and it seems to work as expected. But not if I change the transform in `single_combo` (although it works if used directly, not from `combo`). Do you have an explication?

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing some metaprogramming myself lately, have you looked into boost::mpl::set? That will eliminate duplicates. As for combinations, that sounds to me like mapping, what about boost::mpl::map? Beware that there are library limits that are imposed on the limits of types the sequences can take, though this can be adjusted with a macro, you're still at the mercy of your compiler's upper limit, depending on the number of types you need to handle.