# C++ combinatorial template expansion

Tags: c++, templates

I want to request a series of data from a library, that requires me to specify two types:

```
class a;
class b;
class c;
template<typename A, typename B> void get() {....}

void get_all() {
  get<a,a>()
  get<a,b>()
  get<a,c>()
  get<b,a>()
  get<b,b>()
  // etc...
}
```

I want to call the get<A,B> function for every combination of a set of classes (about 10 different variations) - meaning about 100 different calls.  I'd rather not code all those get() calls by hand.

Is there some way to generate these calls automatically? I suppose I could use preprocessor macros, but I was curious if there was way to generate such a combinatorial list, given a,b,c,d,... by use of template code.

Edit: Minor complication: in fact, this is all in a member function.

```
template<typename A, typename B> 
void Getter::get() 
{  
  auto assn = fMemberObject->RetrieveAllDataOfType<association<A,B>();
  .. do stuff with assn ...
}

void Getter::get_all() {
  get<a,a>();
}
```

So, code needs to deal with passing `this` along with the templates.
Also, C++11 is probably as far as I want to push the language, if possible....

Edit 2:
Turns out I want to avoid the repeated cases `<a,a>` and `<b,b>`...

Comment: I would write a script which generated the code. Or look into the design, to see if I could come up with something which didn't require me to do all those calls. Perhaps if you tell us the problem you are trying to solve with code like that, and we can perhaps help you come up with a better solution? ([Related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), which your question is an example of.)

Comment: What are you doing with the results? Is `get` really `do_some_action`? Because `get` with a `void` return type isn't very meaningful.

Comment: @GManNickG My suspicion is that `get()` has side effects, but clarification from OP would be good.

Comment: That's right. The get() function is actually a class member function that retrieves data from the templated objects and stores in a member object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt on solve a template metaprogramming problem, it helps to think about how to do this in normal programming. In this case, we'd want something like:

```
for a in type_list:
    for b in type_list:
        foo(a,b)
```

So, let's translate that directly into C++. We need a way of representing a type and a typelist:

```
template <class T> struct tag { };
template <class... Ts> struct type_list { };
```

And we need a way of iterating over a type list and doing something for each type. We'll call that something a function invocation. In C++17 (in C++14 and lower, you could use the swallow/expander trick for invoking `f` on each `tag<Ts>`):

```
template <class... Ts, class F>
void for_each(type_list<Ts...>, F f) {
    (f(tag<Ts>{}), ...);
}
```

And that's... basically it actually. We need a function that we're actually calling, a typelist, and code:

```
template <class X, class Y>
void foo(tag<X>, tag<Y> ) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; // or something more meaningful
}

int main() {
    type_list<a, b, c> types;

    for_each(types, [=](auto x){
        for_each(types, [=](auto y){
            foo(x, y);
        });});
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4FzWu4QVKEGzNYU6)

[C++11 version](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CYFCgXSIBKVKlmfC), sort of demonstrating the power of generic lambdas.

---

Based on the update of wanting the types not to be different, this is easy to update too. We can add an equality operator to `tag`:

```
template <class T, class U>
constexpr std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<T,U>::value>
operator==(tag<T>, tag<U> ) { return {}; }

template <class T, class U>
constexpr std::integral_constant<bool, !std::is_same<T,U>::value>
operator!=(tag<T>, tag<U> ) { return {}; }
```

Note that we're not returning `bool`, we're returning a type that encodes the result in the type system. We can then use this naturally:

```
for_each(types, [=](auto x){
    for_each(types, [=](auto y){
        if constexpr (x != y) {
            foo(x, y);
        }
    });});
```

`foo(x,y)` will only be instantiated if the two tag types are different.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to compile.. right up until I try to do something in the foo() function. See my edit above: it now complains that `association<a,b>` is an incomplete type.  I'm not sure why. Editing out the for_each code and calling foo<a,b>() works fine, so I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Nathaniel I can't tell you why code I don't see doesn't work. Probably you're using `association` before it's defined somewhere. But this should allow for arbitrary code in the inner lambda body - assuming the types are all defined at that point.

Comment: Turns out it was an underlying assumption that A not be the same as B.  It was trivial to overload foo() to avoid this.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated** to handle the new requirements that `get()` not be called with identical type parameters, and that `get()` be a class member function. I have called the class `manager` here.

---

You can (ab)use C++11 variadic templates to achieve this.  There is probably a more concise way to do this, but it works and is (hopefully) understandable:

```
struct manager
{
    // Sample implementation of get(), showing the names of the types.
    template <typename A, typename B>
    void get() {
        std::cout << "A=" << typeid(A).name() << " B=" << typeid(B).name() << '\n';
    }
};

// Implementation, uses variadic templates with recursion.
namespace detail
{
    // Helper to delimit template parameter packs.
    template <typename...> struct pack;

    // Terminating case, <=1 type argument(s) means we are done.
    template <typename...>
    struct call_get_all_beta
    {   
        static void call(manager &) { }
    };

    // Invoke get<First, Second>() and recurse with <First, Tail...>.
    template <typename First, typename Second, typename... Tail>
    struct call_get_all_beta<First, Second, Tail...>
    {   
        static void call(manager &m) {
            m.get<First, Second>();
            call_get_all_beta<First, Tail...>::call(m);
        }
    };

    // Specialization to handle skipping over types that are the same.
    template <typename First, typename... Tail>
    struct call_get_all_beta<First, First, Tail...>
    {   
        static void call(manager &m) {
            call_get_all_beta<First, Tail...>::call(m);
        }
    };

    template <typename...>
    struct call_get_all_alpha;

    // Terminating case, first pack is empty.
    template <typename... B>
    struct call_get_all_alpha<pack<>, pack<B...>>
    {   
        static void call(manager &) { }
    };

    // Pass <FirstA, B...> on to call_get_all_beta, recurse with
    // <pack<TailA...>, pack<B...>>.
    template <typename FirstA, typename... TailA, typename... B>
    struct call_get_all_alpha<pack<FirstA, TailA...>, pack<B...>>
    {   
        static void call(manager &m) {
            call_get_all_beta<FirstA, B...>::call(m);
            call_get_all_alpha<pack<TailA...>, pack<B...>>::call(m);
        }
    };
}

// Helper to call the implementation detail.
template <typename... Types>
void get_all_permutations(manager &m)
{
    detail::call_get_all_alpha<detail::pack<Types...>, detail::pack<Types...>>::call(m);
}
```

Then we just do `get_all_permutations<a, b, c>();`. ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7537be6dfef940c9))

To explain how this works, `detail::call_get_all_alpha` takes two `pack<...>` template arguments, both initially contain the entire set of types.  The second one remains the same but each type is peeled off of the first pack each time it recurses.  The first type and the complete set of types (via the second pack) are passed to `detail::call_get_all_beta`, which uses the same "peeling" recursive technique to turn `<A, B, C, D>` into calls to `get<A, B>()`, `get<A, C>()`, and `get<A, D>()`.

So at a higher level, `detail::call_get_all_alpha` is responsible for iterating the *first* template parameter to `get()`, and `detail::call_get_all_beta` is responsible for iterating the *second* template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like:

```
class a;
class b;
class c;
template<typename A, typename B> void get() { /*....*/ }

namespace detail {
    template <typename> struct tag{};

    template <typename Tuple, std::size_t...Is>
    void get_all_pairs(tag<Tuple>, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value;
#if 1 // Folding expression with C++17
        (get<std::tuple_element_t<Is / size, Tuple>,
             std::tuple_element_t<Is % size, Tuple>>(), ...);
#else
        const dummy[] = {0, (get<std::tuple_element_t<Is / size, Tuple>,
                                 std::tuple_element_t<Is % size, Tuple>>(),
                             void(), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable.
#endif
    }

    template <typename ... Ts>
    void get_all_pairs() {
        get_all_pairs(tag<std::tuple<Ts...>>{},
                      std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts) * sizeof...(Ts)>{});
    }

}

void get_all() { detail::get_all_pairs<a, b, c>(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

If Boost is available to you, you can avoid a lot of the basic typelist and application boilerplate, resulting in code that's much easier to read. No need to reinvent the wheel here.

This example uses Boost.MPL, which has wide compiler support, but I'm sure the equivalent solution in Boost.Hana is much prettier.

First, the functions that generate your pairs (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3322989/87234)):

```
#include <utility>

#include <boost/mpl/fold.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_back.hpp>

// For each element in TList, append to Accumulator
// the type pair<PairFirst, element>.
template <
    typename TList, typename PairFirst, typename Accumulator = boost::mpl::vector<>>
struct generate_pairs_fixed_element :
    boost::mpl::fold<
        TList,
        Accumulator,
        boost::mpl::push_back<boost::mpl::_1, std::pair<PairFirst, boost::mpl::_2>>>
{};

// For each element in TList, concatenate to Accumulator
// the result of generate_pairs_fixed_element<TList, element>.
template <typename TList, typename Accumulator = boost::mpl::vector<>>
struct generate_pairs_combinations :
    boost::mpl::fold<
        TList,
        Accumulator,
        boost::mpl::lambda<
            generate_pairs_fixed_element<TList, boost::mpl::_2, boost::mpl::_1>
        >>
{};
```

Now just gather up your types into a list and generate the combinations:

```
class a {};
class b {};
class c {};
class d {};

typedef boost::mpl::vector<a, b, c, d> all_classes_t;

typedef generate_pairs_combinations<all_classes_t>::type all_classes_pairs_t;
```

And do whatever you want with them:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/type.hpp>

template <typename A, typename B>
void get() {
    std::cout << "Getting " << typeid(A).name()
              << " and " << typeid(B).name() << std::endl;
}

struct pair_visitor {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    void operator()(boost::type<std::pair<T, U>>) const {
        get<T, U>();
    }
};

int main() {
    boost::mpl::for_each<all_classes_pairs_t, boost::type<boost::mpl::_>>(pair_visitor());
}
```